# Export layered SVGs from GPlates to GIMP

Tags: export, gimp

I'm using both [GPlates](http://gplates.org/) and GIMP for the project I'm working on, and I need to export a layered image from GPlates to the GIMP.

Is it possible to export a layered SVG (or any format) from GPlates to GIMP that can still be read by the latter? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GPlates, but I've used Inkscape for SVGs many times, and have exported to PNG from there, which can then be read by the GIMP.  Is this an option for you?  Ie, use Inkscape to read in the SVG and export to PNG for use in GIMP?  Or can GPlates export to PNG directly?

Comment: GPlates can export to PNG, but the main issue is that I need to have layers in the exported file; specifically a way to disable the gridlines that are also exported with the image.